# How can we identify vue popover trigger happened anywhere in the full project(many pages)?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I am using v-b-popover everywhere in my project(many pages).
I need to know whenever we click or hover on popover button on any page, then how can we know that trigger happened.

I wanted to know without writing any events on attributes of that element(popover).

Is there any way?

Comment: Have you considered using a plain JavaScript [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect when the button or popover element changes?

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for events on `$root`, as each popover fires the same event on `$root` when shown.

```js
this.$root.$on('bv::popover::show', bvEventObj => {
  console.log('bvEventObj:', bvEventObj)
})
```

Reference: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/popover#listening-to-popover-changes-via-root-events

You can also listen for other events than `bv::popover::show`, like `bv::popover::hide`, or `bv::popover::enabled`.
You can see a full list [here](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/popover#comp-ref-b-popover-events).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created() {
    // Listen for an event on the root.
    this.$root.$on('bv::popover::show', () => {
      console.log('Popover Opened')
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>



<div id="app">
  <b-btn v-b-popover.hover.bottom="'Button 1'">Button 1</b-btn>

  <b-btn v-b-popover.hover.bottom="'Button 2'">Button 2</b-btn>

  <b-btn v-b-popover.hover.bottom="'Button 3'">Button 3</b-btn>
</div>
```